# MySQL dump --where="1 limit 2, 3", 1 means what?

Tags: mysql

```
mysqldump -uroot --opt --where="1 limit 2, 3" dbname --no-create-info > bk.sql
```

I use this command to dump partial data of database or dump large database to multiple files and it works well.

As I tested,

`2` means skipping first 2 recoreds,

and `3` means dumping 3 records,

but I don't understand `1` means what in `--where="1 limit 2, 3"`?

Comment: `1` means True, so it goes over all records, skipping 2, then using 3.

Comment: @mbomb007 skip id `2` , or the first `2` records, which one?

Comment: If your question has been solved, please mark an answer as "accepted". If not, let us know with some more information on how we can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), the syntax following `LIMIT` is the offset (number of rows to skip), followed by the number of rows to select.

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

You would also be able to do `LIMIT 3 OFFSET 2`.

As stated in my comment, `WHERE 1` is like saying `WHERE TRUE`, and it will select from all records in the table.

Answer (score 2):

WHERE 1 is a synonym for "true" or "everything" ,  so it won't have any filtering impact on your query.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 0,5
```

will return 5 records starting from the first record.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 5
```

will also give the same result as above query.

If in that table there are fewer than 5 records then it will not fail but return whatever records are there.

Query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 6,5
```

will return record 7,8,9,10,11 as the index starts from 0.